# EJB polls periodically concurrent Queue

Tags: concurrency, queue, ejb, runnable

This is my scenario
i have two singleton EJB. The first one receive some data and writes it in a Queue data structure instantiated by the other EJB.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Client implements IClient {

@EJB
IClientInQueue reporter;
....
@Asynchronous
public void update(String message){
    StatusMessage m = new StatusMessage();
    reporter.addStatusMessage(m);

}


@Startup
@Singleton
public class ClientInQueue implements IClientInQueue {

private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<StatusMessage> statusInQueue;
    addStatusMessage(String m) ..add element to queue
```

This works fine. Now i want to poll periodically this queue and then make some dispatching operation.
My issue is that a i can't use runnable in ejb context. I'm looking to migrate to spring, but first of make this i want to know if i'm missing something.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... now I want to poll periodically this queue..

If you need execute some code periodically, the Java EE specification provides a service called [Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) that is useful in these cases. This service gives you the posibility to execute your code at a defined interval time.

> My issue is that a i can't use runnable in ejb context.

Since Java EE 7 (JSR 236: Concurrency Utilities), exists the possibility to create a [managed thread](https://concurrency-ee-spec.java.net/javadoc/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html), which allows you run new threads within a Container in a safe way.